# Rails-Api limits length of url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, url-encoding

When sending a request to my rails app:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3334/v1/api/notebooks/users/verified/courses/None/files/asset-v1%3AedX%2BDemoX%2BDemo_Course%2Btype%40asset%2Bblock%40Welcome_R__-_demo.ipynb
```

I notice that params that rails passes to the controller are:

```
Parameters: {"username"=>"verified", "course"=>"None", "file"=>"asset-v1:edX+DemoX+Demo_Course+type@asset+block@Welcome_R__-_demo"}
```

It has removed the period, or .fileextension. I realise this is because rails seems to have some set maximum length for a url. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of a URL is usually pulled out as `params[:format]`. You can avoid this by specifying your path as `/*path`, but usually putting the format parameter back on is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely long URLs are usually a mistake. URLs over 2,000 characters will not work in the most popular web browser. Don't use them if you intend your site to work for the majority of Internet users.

When you wish to submit a form containing many fields, which would otherwise produce a very long URL, the standard solution is to use the `POST` method rather than the `GET` method:

```
<form action="myaction" method="POST">
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: Your URL to check on the limits redirects to a bank loan page.  Please update with something useful, otherwise this is just spam.

Comment: @JeffK I can't get how your comment is related to the answer?

Comment: The link you give in "Check more about limits here" resolves to a bank loan page...it might have resolved to something useful at a previous time, but now, its a dead-end.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, yes the answer is 6 years ago, I removed the link